# Crystal Reports Cross Tabs Growing Into Each Other

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report with several crosstabs in the report header.  The problem is that some of them grow down into the ones below them.  Is there an option to have each crosstab dynamically determine its starting position based on the end of the previous one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create multiple report header sections and put one crosstab in each